# 5 Volt Regulator 120 mA no Heat Sink

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, 5v, lm317

What is a better DC-DC Voltage Regulator than LM317, I am making a 5V Regulator to Drive an IC that takes 5V at 110 mA, but the LM317 draws 2 W power and gets HOT and the box I use does not have Room for a heat sink.   Is a  switcher DC-DC supply any better ?

Comment: What's your input voltage?

Comment: And how do you know the LM317 is drawing 2W?

Comment: Input voltage 20V.   The LM317 is dropping 15 V across it so it must be dissipating 15V at 110 mA  ( E * I ) or 1.65 W of Power.

Comment: Case Temperature is at 50 Degrees C or 120 Degrees F

Comment: Thanks -- I wanted to make sure you weren't mistaking the rated power of the device to the actual power dissipation.

Comment: Can I use a switcher 5V regulator instead of the LM317 ?

Comment: there are actually drop-in SMPS replacements for 78xx regulators.

Answer (score 2):

A switcher will almost certainly be better.  You should be able to find a buck module that will drop 18V down to 5V.  Shop carefully -- there's older design modules out there that aren't very efficient.  You should expect 80% to 95% efficiency.

If you're willing to go for it, you can build a switcher onto your board from one of the many chips out there.  If you're constrained to a through-hole design, though, I recommend that you just get a module.